# How do I find out which memcache version is compatible with PHP version?

Tags: php, memcached

In the past it's always been trial & error for the different memcache versions to see which one works.

Are there any lists to which memcache version is compatible with which PHP versions?

At the moment I am running both:
- PHP 5.2.17
- PHP 5.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very basic lists, but as far as I could find when I had the same issue as you, there aren't any detailed ones like you are looking for.

You will have to continue with trial and error until someone produces a more detailed list unfortunately.